# How to get a list of video capture devices (web cameras) on linux ( ubuntu )? (C/C++)

Tags: c++, c, linux, webcam, device

So all I need is simple - a list of currently avaliable video capture devices (web cameras). I need it in simple C or C++ console app. By list I mean something like such console output:

```
1) Asus Web Camera
2) Sony Web Camera
```

So It seems simple but I have one requirement - use of native OS apis as much as possible - no external libs - after all - all we want is to print out a a list - not to fly onto the moon!)

How to do such thing?

---

also from this series:

- [How to get a list of video capture devices on linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290834/how-to-get-a-list-of-video-capture-devices-web-cameras-on-linux-ubuntu-c) and [special details on getting cameras NAMES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483366/how-to-get-a-list-video-capture-devices-names-web-cameras-on-linux-ubuntu) with correct, tested answers
- [How to get a list of video capture devices on Mac OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532263/how-to-get-a-list-of-video-capture-devices-web-cameras-on-mac-os-c) with correct, not yet tested by my answers
- [How to get a list of video capture devices on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286223/how-to-get-a-list-of-video-capture-devices-web-cameras-on-windows-c) with correct, tested answers
- [How to get a list video capture devices NAMES using Qt (crossplatform)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637594/how-to-get-a-list-video-capture-devices-names-web-cameras-using-qt-crossplatfo)

Comment: Can you get it from /proc/bus/input/devices

Comment: The question is how exactly to do it from code?

Comment: Minimal runnable example of how to read the camera, process it on GPU, and show both on a window live: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13693946/image-processing-with-glsl-shaders/40641014#40641014

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a code snippet I had laying around. Probably from a book. I guess you could just iterate over all /dev/videoN nodes and get the info.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/videodev.h>

int main(){
    int fd;
    struct video_capability video_cap;
    struct video_window     video_win;
    struct video_picture   video_pic;

    if((fd = open("/dev/video0", O_RDONLY)) == -1){
        perror("cam_info: Can't open device");
        return 1;
    }

    if(ioctl(fd, VIDIOCGCAP, &video_cap) == -1)
        perror("cam_info: Can't get capabilities");
    else {
        printf("Name:\t\t '%s'\n", video_cap.name);
        printf("Minimum size:\t%d x %d\n", video_cap.minwidth, video_cap.minheight);
        printf("Maximum size:\t%d x %d\n", video_cap.maxwidth, video_cap.maxheight);
    }

    if(ioctl(fd, VIDIOCGWIN, &video_win) == -1)
        perror("cam_info: Can't get window information");
    else
        printf("Current size:\t%d x %d\n", video_win.width, video_win.height);

    if(ioctl(fd, VIDIOCGPICT, &video_pic) == -1)
        perror("cam_info: Can't get picture information");
    else
        printf("Current depth:\t%d\n", video_pic.depth);

    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: and ho to iterate thrue N? (we do not know N do we?)

Comment: Right we have to guess a big enough N. Use the accept() function to check what /dev/video nodes with n from 0..N exist. See the accepted answer over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230062/whats-the-best-way-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-c-cross-platform

Comment: This answer is ridiculously overcomplicated in light of @GregyCat's below.

Answer (score 59):

You can use the following bash command:

```
v4l2-ctl --list-devices
```

In order to use the above command, you  must install package ***v4l-utils*** before. In Ubuntu/Debian you can use the command:

```
sudo apt-get install v4l-utils
```

Comment: For those on Arch Linux, `v4l2-ctl` is provided in the `v4l-utils` package.

Comment: I found using ```v4l2-ctl --list-devices``` to be the best answer for my particular problem. I ended up using it for a simple python configurator. Gist [here](https://gist.github.com/kphretiq/e5b95e7fc2b11819121e).

Answer (score 40):

It's easy by just traversing sysfs devices by a given class. The following command-line one liner would do so:

```
for I in /sys/class/video4linux/*; do cat $I/name; done
```

You can do the same thing in C/C++ application, by just opening up `/sys/class/video4linux` directory, it will have symlinks to all your web cameras as video4linux devices:

```
$ ls -al /sys/class/video4linux                          
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 Ноя 27 12:19 ./
drwxr-xr-x 34 root root 0 Ноя 26 00:08 ../
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Ноя 27 12:19 video0 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.2/usb2/2-5/2-5:1.0/video4linux/video0/
```

You can follow every symlink to a directory of every device and read full contents of `name` file in that directory to get the name.

Comment: @Kabumbus the 1-liner above is quite good, and easy to transform into a c code. +1 from me

Comment: One-liner perfect for me. Thanks! Easy peasy to insert into any code.

Comment: Worked on adb shell as root as well.

Answer (score 0):

V4L2 documentation says that there can be 64 allowed devices for each type. For instance for path /dev/video there can be 64 devices addresssed as /dev/video0, /dev/video1, /dev/video2 ...

Iterate over 64 devices until the ioctl retuens ENIVAL which specifies end of the tree.