# Raspberry pi Ip webcam image grab

Tags: linux, save, webcam, raspberry-pi, timelapse

I have an Ip webcam that shows an image on it's small webserver. I want my raspberry pi to grab these images and save them with a date and time. Sort of like a timelapse. The camera is supposed to only be connected over the internet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a list of video capture devices (web cameras) on linux ( ubuntu )? (C/C++)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290834/how-to-get-a-list-of-video-capture-devices-web-cameras-on-linux-ubuntu-c)

Comment: No, Im trying to grab a picture off an online source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wget` is your friend here. It's a program made to download files from the command line. Does the picture have a static URL? If so, it will be as easy as:

```
wget -O `date "+%m-%d-%H%M"`.jpg http://example.com/camera/thepicture.jpg
```

In this command, `-O` signifies that wget should write the downloaded file to the name

```
`date "+%m-%d-%H%M"`.jpg
```

If you're not familiar with the `date` program, it outputs the current system time and date in a format you specify -- the format string I showed here means "month-day-HourMinute" (on a 24-hour clock). So,  if I ran this command right now, I would end up with a file named `08-13-1338.jpg`.

This is basically the simplest possible case, but you haven't given too much information about the problem. If this solution doesn't meet your needs, please provide further information about the problem.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed. Where can I specify where to save the file to?

Comment: Just add a path before the `date` command, like this: `wget -O /home/pictures/`date "+%m-%d-%H%M"`.jpg`. Happy coding :)

Comment: Excuse the poor formatting of my previous comment, apparently you can't use <code></code> tags in comments and so nested backticks do not show up. Regardless, to specify where to save the file, just add a path before the `date` command