# Embed usb web camera video in to wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython, video-streaming, vlc, raspberry-pi2

I need to display the USB camera video of raspberry-pi in Wxpython with control buttons in it. I have managed to embed vlc in to Wxpython with control buttons (Got it from Google) to play existing video. Is there any way to stream the USB camera video in it?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've managed to embed VLC, you should just be able to point it at the v4l address for the webcam.

The v4l address should be along the lines of v4l:/dev/video0:size=640x480 (but it'll vary depending on your machine I guess). You may find it easier to use the standalone VLC client to get the address you need and then put it into your program.

This [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290834/how-to-get-a-list-of-video-capture-devices-web-cameras-on-linux-ubuntu-c) may be useful for later depending on what you're doing.