# Can OpenCV 2.2 provide cameras devices names for me?

Tags: c++, opencv

Can OpenCV 2.2 provide cameras devices names for me?

Why I ask - normally (on Mac and Linux) simple hand written camera index lister (like [this one here](http://code.google.com/p/cloudobserver/source/browse/trunk/CloudObserverClientCrossplatform/Code/list.cpp?r=946) based on [this research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532263/how-to-get-a-list-of-video-capture-devices-web-cameras-on-mac-os-c)) works for 2.2.0 but on windows it works for OpeCV 2.1 and minor versions. And when you get on to 2.2.0 you for example start expiriencing problems

- With ALL wirtual cameras
- [With lots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749498/cant-access-webcam-with-opencv) of non virtual cameras.

And I tall you - it sucks when your code worked all across all platforms and than broke.

[They say](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749498/cant-access-webcam-with-opencv/5313594#5313594)  OpenCV can be recompiled manually with `HAVE_VIDEOINPUT HAVE_DSHOW` options... but I (C++ kind of beginner) really would like to see either a tutorial (step by step on to recompile openCV with such params for example from my vs08) or, better solution a way to get capturable camera names from OpenCV to be capable to say to user something like

> We use OpenCV for camera capture and It has not found ANY CAPTURABLE DEVICES ON YOUR MACHINE AT ALL (while we bouth now you have at least 2) Go, buzz openCV community.

second option is rude. and I am deeply sorry but please OpenCV guys help us all save the world - provide cameras names lister=)

Comment: [off-topic]: Welcome back! :)

Comment: I think it could be an outdated question (or needs some update) as we are now at OpenCV 2.4.3.

Comment: sad to find that opencv video capture still don't provide this in 2.4.11 or 3.0x, which might kill my weekend for those directshow codes....