# Maemo 5 Qt: how to capture frame (RGB) from first and second camera?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, video, maemo

So (I havent tried yet) but it somehow seems that [video for linux 2 will work](http://wiki.maemo.org/Documentation/Maemo_5_Developer_Guide/Using_Multimedia_Components/Camera_API_Usage)... But I wonder is it possible to do such thing with for pure qt libs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Qt Mobility [QtMultiMediaKit](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.1.0-beta/multimedia.html) extension (`libqtm-multimedia-dev` package) and then use [`QCamera`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.1.0-beta/qcamera.html) in conjunction with [`QCameraImageCapture`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.1.0-beta/qcameraimagecapture.html) to capture frames. To activate the front-facing secondary camera, construct your camera like this:

```
QCamera *camera = new QCamera(QCamera::availableDevices()[1]);
```

Comment: As I see such lib would work under windows and linux and mac http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.1.0-beta/index.html so could you please post your correct answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637594/how-to-get-a-list-video-capture-devices-names-web-cameras-using-qt-crossplatfo