# Get web-cams list using VLC command line

Tags: java, vlc

**How I can get  web-cams list using VLC command line?**

If I using FFmpeg, I can write:

```
$ ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
```

and get list of names web-cameras that I can using into the scripts to get video from this web-cameras.

**How I can do the same using VLC?**

Comment: You might be able to enumerate them yourself programmatically...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, this is not possible to do through VLC itself. You will probably have to do this through your OS. Although, there maybe a plugin that allows for this.

This blog article contains a section that discusses doing something like this on Ubuntu Linux but involves having to physically plug the camera in:
http://clusterbleep.net/blog/2010/07/13/webcam-recording-using-vlc-on-linux/

However, there is more in-depth treatment in this Stackoverflow question on how to get a list of cameras through the OS. It lists a series of other articles for each major OS:
[How to get a list of video capture devices (web cameras) on linux ( ubuntu )? (C/C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290834/how-to-get-a-list-of-video-capture-devices-web-cameras-on-linux-ubuntu-c)

Comment: Thank's for reply! But the most important think for me is **how to get names of web-cameras on Windows**?

Comment: @vanveber If you are looking for ideas on how to get a list of cameras on Windows, here is an article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286223/how-to-get-a-list-of-video-capture-devices-web-cameras-on-windows-c