# How do I get a Handle to a device with SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo?

Tags: c++, windows, device, handle

I want to open a handle to my camera device using CreateFile(), but I do not have the device path.

I know I can get the device path with the SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail inside SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces. However I have a problem getting the interfaces for the camera devices.

I for example tried to use SetupDiGetClassDevs with KEYBOARD GUID, it works perfectly. I got the interfaces data and associated device paths. It also works for several GUID.

The problem appears with some GUID such as Camera (the one I want) . Apparently my camera device doesn't have any interface.

Is there a way to get a device path directly within the SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo loop?

Or what parameter from the SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty can I pass to CreateFile to get a valid handle?

```
int getDeviceHandlesByClass(WCHAR* inputClassName)
{
    HDEVINFO hDevInfoSet;
    SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData;
    DWORD i = 0;

    hDevInfoSet = SetupDiGetClassDevs(NULL, NULL, NULL, DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_ALLCLASSES);

    if (hDevInfoSet == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        std::cout << "Error on SetupDiGetClassDevs" << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    DeviceInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA);

    while (SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(hDevInfoSet, i, &DeviceInfoData))
    {
        i++;

        WCHAR deviceClassName[256];
        if (!SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(hDevInfoSet, &DeviceInfoData, SPDRP_CLASS, NULL, (BYTE*)deviceClassName, sizeof(deviceClassName), NULL))
        {
            return 1;
        }

        if (wcscmp(deviceClassName, inputClassName) == 0)
        {
            std::wcout << "PDO: " << deviceClassName << std::endl;
        }

        DWORD size;
        WCHAR instanceID[256];
        if (SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId(hDevInfoSet, &DeviceInfoData, instanceID, 256, &size))
        {
            std::wcout << "INSTANCE ID: " << instanceID << std::endl;
        }

        HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(L"???WHAT SHALL I PASS HERE???", // file path
            GENERIC_READ, // desired access
            FILE_SHARE_READ, // share mode
            NULL, // security attributes
            OPEN_EXISTING, // creation disposition
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, // file attributes
            NULL);             // template file

        if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            // Handle error
            cout << GetLastError() << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "test" << endl;
        }

        // Close the file handle
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        

    }

    SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(hDevInfoSet);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286223/how-to-get-a-list-of-video-capture-devices-web-cameras-on-windows-c